# Make drop down list default value selected in Excel using spreadsheet gear + VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, spreadsheetgear

I am using below code to create a dropdownlist in Excel with "Yes,No" vallues displayed, but initially it is showing blank

**worksheet.Range("I4:I5").Validation.Add(ValidationType.List, ValidationAlertStyle.Information, ValidationOperator.Default, "Yes,No", Nothing)**

Initially I want default to set to "No", and the excel cell should be appear with arrow initially- which is not happening

Please help me out, how to do this using spreadsheet gear in VB.Net

THanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding validation to a cell does not automatically populate that cell with a given value, nor does it select the cell (which would make the "arrow" appear, which I think is a reference to the dropdown handle?).

To make these additional things happen, you'll need to explicitly set the cell value via the IRange.[Value](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Value.html) property and select the desired cell via the IRange.[Select](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Select.html)() method.  Example:

```
' Get reference to range affected.
Dim range = worksheet.Range("I4:I5")

' Apply validation.
range.Validation.Add(ValidationType.List, ValidationAlertStyle.Information, 
    ValidationOperator.Default, "Yes,No", Nothing)

' Set initial values of cells to "No".
range.Value = "No"

' Select the first cell in the affected range, I4.  Calling select
' directly on "range" would select both I4 and I5.
range(0, 0).Select()
```